# How to Add header to child list in ExpandListVie

Tags: android

How to Add header to child list in ExpandListView like this

```
AvailableTasks       =============     Parent
TaskNo   TaskName    Status
-----------------------------
  1        read      progress      |
-----------------------------      |
  2        listen    pending       |   Childs
-----------------------------      |
  3       walking   started        |
-----------------------------      |
```

any help is needed urgently, is appreciated

Comment: did you try to add headerview to your list???
also if possible put your code so that we can figure out what exactly is needed

Answer (score 0):

in your getChildrenCount you increase to 1 for header of your group like:

```
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return "your children group count" + 1;
}
```

and in getChildView you check the first child of group and return your header of group like

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(childPosition == 0){
         return "your header of group view";
    }
    // your original code here, note that, the childPosition is increased to 1
}
```

Hope this help.